# how to apply pagination in dc.js datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am using dc.js chart for datatable. For applying pagination i used code:-

```
           datatable = $(".dc-data-table").dataTable({
           remaining part of code...
```

When i am running code it display error

```
            $(....).datatable is not a function.
```

I am using js file of jquery and dc chart. I checked out jquery is working correct.

Why the above errors appear?

Please suggest me some advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you include the 3rd party plugin?

Comment: I included plugin which are in dc chart

Comment: mind to show the html also? and part of the code, if able to, create a sample fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ for easier troublshoot your problem, still, I suspect you might not include the js script as wanted. Try to clear the browser cache